# Does hibernate spatial support st_geometry created by ArcSDE?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, hibernate-spatial

We are using ArcSDE 10.0 to export data to the Oracle database, and the spatial property are saved using the `SDE.st_geometry` format.

Now in our J2EE application we tried to manage these data by hibernate spatial.

And hs support Oracle Spatial out of box, but it have no documents about the `st_geometry` for ArcSDE.

So I wonder if we can use it for `st_geometry` ?  If not, is it possible to extend the functions of hs?

---

Update:

This is my dialect, and I register two functions `overlaps` and `length`:

```
public class Oracle11gSTGeometrySpatialDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public Oracle11gSTGeometrySpatialDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("overlaps", new STFunction(new BooleanType(), "sde.st_overlaps(?1,sde.st_geometry(?2,3))"));
        registerFunction("length", new SQLFunctionTemplate(new DoubleType(), "sde.st_length(?1)"));
    }
}
```

And the query:

```
Query q=em.createQuery("from HBDS h where length(h.shape) > -1");
```

However the generated sql is invalid:

```
select hbds0_.objectId as objectId1_0_, st_astext(hbds0_.shape) as shape4_0_ from TEST_BDS hbds0_ where sde.st_length(st_astext(hbds0_.shape))>-1
```

While the valid sql should be:

```
select hbds0_.objectId as objectId1_0_, st_astext(hbds0_.shape) as shape4_0_ from TEST_BDS hbds0_ where sde.st_length(hbds0_.shape)>-1
```

It seems that this is caused by the `ColumnTransformer` annotation.

I am surprised that your example works as expected?

Now I can use the native query:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select st_astext(shape) from TEST_BDS h where sde.st_overlaps(h.shape, st_geometry(?,3)) = 1");
q.setParameter(1, JTS.defaultGeometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y)).toText());
```

It works, but there are some cons:

1 I have to write the select fields manually since I can not use `select *` which will be a problem once I have a lot of fileds in the entity.

2 I can not count the row count for the specified query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a project for Hibernate which adds support for ST_geometry.
Currently Postgresql and Oracle are supported.

You can find it here:
 http://bitbucket.schuller.lu/hibernatestgeometry

It's still beta, but first tests are very promising.
I'm using the WKT/WKB representation to read or update the geometry in the database.

It looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dau_track")
public class DauTrack {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "st_geometry")
    @Type(type = "lu.schuller.arcgisStGeometry.WkbStGeometryType")
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "st_asbinary(shape)", write = "st_geomfromwkb(?,2169)")
    private Polyline shape;
```

I created my own Wkb-HibernateType to convert the wkb-data betweent database and geometry-api.
I have already implemented JTS and esri-geomeotry as geo-libraries.

The 'columnTransformers' are modifiing the generated hibernate-sql to read and write under wkb-form in the database.

It's currently running under postgresql and underOracle.

Comment: Nice job, but the link is dead.

Comment: http://bitbucket.schuller.lu/hibernatestgeometry

Comment: I forked it and make it work locally, and I have made a small fix which I have created a pull request. And one more thing, how about if I want to use some spatial function like `st_overlap` in the query ?

Comment: Is it possible to make it support the spatial functions as I mentioned in the previous comment?

Comment: Would be possible with native query.
Or defining them as hibernate-functions, similar as in the hibernate-spatial project

Comment: spatial functions are possible, just committed an example with 'st_length'

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is the way the hibernate spatial used. Maybe you can push this to the official hibernate spatial library.

Comment: I already looked quickly how to integrate it Ingo hibernate-spatial, but didn't found directly an easy way. Maxbe somebody other could help me in this who knows hibernate-spatial? You can ask it in their forum/mailinglist (I'm very busy these days)

Answer (score 0):

Just added simple support for ST_geometry functions to:
 http://bitbucket.schuller.lu/hibernatestgeometry

Here a possible hibernate query using the 'st_length' function

> em.createQuery("from MyLine where **st_length(shape)** > 2000").getResultList();

Comment: I update my post